# How can i view particular user activities

Tags: magento-1.9, user-roles, admin-user

How can i view user updated like add products, deleted products any others changes in magento.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

credits : **@Fabian Blechschmidt**

Not an Out of the box, you can use this [module](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring)

But once you install this module, This extension writes a lot of data into the database, read the complete documentation provided in the link....

```
class FireGento_AdminMonitoring_Adminhtml_HistoryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Inits the layout, the active menu tab and the breadcrumbs
     *
     * @return FireGento_AdminMonitoring_Adminhtml_HistoryController
     */
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('system/history');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(
            $this->getMonitoringHelper()->__('Admin Monitoring'),
            $this->getMonitoringHelper()->__('History')
        );

        $this->_title($this->getMonitoringHelper()->__('Admin Monitoring'))
            ->_title($this->getMonitoringHelper()->__('History'));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the history grid
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Reload the adminhtml history grid, for
     */
    public function gridAction()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('firegento_adminmonitoring/adminhtml_history_grid');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }

    /**
     * View a single history grid
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        /* @var $history FireGento_AdminMonitoring_Model_History */
        $history = Mage::getModel('firegento_adminmonitoring/history')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if (!$history->getId()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*');

            return;
        }

        Mage::register('current_history', $history, true);

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Reverts a history entry
     */
    public function revertAction()
    {
        /* @var $history FireGento_AdminMonitoring_Model_History */
        $history = Mage::getModel('firegento_adminmonitoring/history')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if ($history->getId()) {
            $model = $history->getOriginalModel();
            $model->addData($history->getDecodedContentDiff());
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                $this->getMonitoringHelper()->__(
                    'Revert of %1$s with id %2$d successful',
                    $history->getObjectType(),
                    $history->getObjectId()
                )
            );
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the adminmonitoring helper
     *
     * @return FireGento_AdminMonitoring_Helper_Data
     */
    public function getMonitoringHelper()
    {
        return Mage::helper('firegento_adminmonitoring');
    }

    /**
     * Check is allowed access to action - needed afer security patch SUPEE-6285
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('system/history');
    }
}
```

Comment: may slow down when is use this extensions,, right ??

Comment: read the complete documentation provided in the link.